# Cannot log in to Windows from dual boot Grub

Tags: dual-boot

Here is the boot repair report but: https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/2q3GWSW9P2/

I am not able to log in into windows after installing ubuntu:

I tried all usual solutions - update grub, os-prober etc but no luck. I can see windows in grub list but it shows dell logo and loops back to the same grub menu.

Comment: In BIOS, select the partition where Windows is located to boot Windows. **Turn off Fast Startup** -- the error you are getting in the boot-repair output is telling you that Windows is hibernated. Apparently you installed Ubuntu while Windows was in this state. You need to turn off the hybrid hibernate if you want to dual boot.  If selecting Windows in your motherboard BIOS doesn't work, ask on SuperUser, because that means Windows itself is broken. We can't advise if the problem exists 100% on the Windows side.

Comment: Some more details on Nmath's suggestion. https://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/unable-to-mount-windows-10-partition-it-is-in-an-unsafe-state & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation